# Firebase dependency issue

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

Hell everyone, i'm new to flutter and after some courses have been able to develop cool apps and design. But to take further my learning I was led to link FireStore with my android application.
And when I do so, I get this error message, once I declare dependencies in the pubspect.yaml file:

```
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


And some more errors of the same
I tried creating an application from scratch again and before designing any layout to do the Firestore integration first then once fine, move on to the code and design

THIS IS THE ERROR GENERATED ON A EMPTY PROJECT I CREATED, Please HELP ME SOLVING IT

 [Fatal Error] error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':cloud_firestore:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.6.0
> Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0.
> Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.2.0/error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.pom
> Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.3.0 > com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre
> Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0.
> Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.2.0/error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.pom
> Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cloud_firestore' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        24.2s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

HOW TO SOLVE IT?
These are the dependencies I added to the .yaml file
dependencies:

```
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0

  firebase_auth: ^0.15.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.1.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+1
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
```

Comment: did you make sure that you added package with correct spacing ?

Comment: Yes! The package Get command is working just fine. The error comes when I " flutter run" it. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the error that you are facing is related to your Gradle version. 
Searching by the error `Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler`, I could find some cases that seems related to yours.

You can access these cases here:

- [Gradle Sync failed: Could not find method implementation()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242480/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-find-method-implementation)
- [Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':react-native-maps', build_czs7godsj0vcwov8vklieva36$_run_closure2$_closure12@204d9edf] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. #2211](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2211)
- [Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989943/could-not-find-method-implementation-for-arguments-com-google-firebasefireba)

Considering that, could you please take a look at them and confirm if using the latest Gradle version fixes your case?

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: This quite helped! The 1st link. I changed the gradle version and changed from implementation to compile

Thanks a ton!

But a project I got from another computer did not need these changes!